# How do I get word2vec to load a string? problem：'dict' object has no attribute '_load_specials'

Tags: python-3.x, lstm, word2vec

I have a problem when using word2vec and lstm, the code is:

```
def input_transform(string):
    words=jieba.lcut(string)
    words=np.array(words).reshape(1,-1)
    model=Word2Vec.load('lstm_datamodel.pkl')
    combined=create_dictionaries(model,words)
    return combined

def lstm_predict(string):
    print ('loading model......')
    with open('lstm_data.yml', 'r') as f:
        yaml_string = yaml.load(f)
    model = model_from_yaml(yaml_string)

    print ('loading weights......')
    model.load_weights('lstm_data.h5')
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
    data=input_transform(string)
    data.reshape(1,-1)
    #print data
    result=model.predict_classes(data)
    if result[0][0]==1:
        print (string,' positive')
    else:
        print (string,' negative')
```

and the error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\word2vec.py", line 1312, in load
model = super(Word2Vec, cls).load(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\base_any2vec.py", line 1244, in load
model = super(BaseWordEmbeddingsModel, cls).load(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\base_any2vec.py", line 603, in load
return super(BaseAny2VecModel, cls).load(fname_or_handle, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\gensim\utils.py", line 423, in load
obj._load_specials(fname, mmap, compress, subname)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute '_load_specials'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/GitHub/reviewsentiment/veclstm.py", line 211, in <module>
lstm_predict(string)
File "C:/GitHub/reviewsentiment/veclstm.py", line 191, in lstm_predict
data=input_transform(string)
File "C:/GitHub/reviewsentiment/veclstm.py", line 177, in input_transform
model=Word2Vec.load('lstm_datamodel.pkl')
File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\word2vec.py", line 1323, in load
return load_old_word2vec(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\deprecated\word2vec.py", line 153, in load_old_word2vec
old_model = Word2Vec.load(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\deprecated\word2vec.py", line 1618, in load
model = super(Word2Vec, cls).load(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\deprecated\old_saveload.py", line 88, in load
obj._load_specials(fname, mmap, compress, subname)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute '_load_specials'enter code here
```

I am sorry for including so much code.

This is my first time to ask on StackOverflow, and I have tried my very best to find the answer on my own, but failed. So can you help me? Thank you very much!

Comment: // , Welcome to Stack Overflow. Better to have too much code, than to have too little. Would you be willing to please say what research you have done already on this before asking on Stack Overflow? Also, can you rephrase your question to be in the English question format (e.g. ending with a "?")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is occurring on the line...

```
model=Word2Vec.load('lstm_datamodel.pkl')
```

...so all the other/later code you've supplied is irrelevant and superfluous.

The suffix of your filename, `lstm_datamodel.pkl`, suggests it may have been created via Python's `pickle()` facility. The `gensim` `Word2Vec.load()` method only expects to load models that were saved by the module's own `save()` routine, *not* any pickled object.

The `gensim` native `save()` does make use of pickle for some of its saving, but not all, and thus wouldn't expect a fully-pickled object in the file provided.

This might be cause of your problem. You could try instead a load based entirely on Python `pickle`:

```
model = pickle.load('lstm_datamodel.pkl')
```

Alternatively, if you can reconstruct the model in the file, but be sure to save it via the native gensim `model.save(filename)`, that might also resolve the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much !  The error can be fixed by using  (model.save(filename)), and with your help i can try to figure it! Thanks a lot !!